# Как можно сделать, чтобы при редиректе не менялся адрес в строке браузера?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть страница http://optom8.ru/

Как сделат, чтобы при попадании на эту страницу пользователь перенаправлялся на страницу http://optom8.ru/wppage/5-prostyih-shagov-kak-zarabotat-v-opte-2/, а в строке браузера оставался адрес http://optom8.ru/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

1. Использовать ajax-загрузку страницы, тоесть подключить `jquery` и при нажатии на ссылку не перенаправлять на страницу, а исполнять код:

   ```
   $('body').load('ссылка')
   ```
2. В загружаемой странице вставить такой скрипт:

   ```
   window.onload = function(){
      history.replaceState({}, 'название страницы', '/')
   }
   ```

Comment: А второй вариант в какое место кода вставлять? И надо ли его в какие то тэги заносить?

Comment: И первый вариант как можно к странице подключить? Скажите пожалуйста. Очень нужно.

Comment: Дело в том, что ссылки нет. Адрес печаатается в строку браузера

Comment: @Pavlik290592, для начала стоит почитать об основах `html` и `javascript`. Если адрес печатается в адресную строку браузера — подойдёт только второй вариант. Что-бы код работал, нужно в любом месте на странице материала вставить:

    window.onload = function(){
       history.replaceState({}, 'название страницы', '/')
    }

Comment: Я так понимаю, что это не во всех браузерах работает? Это с HTML5?

Comment: Куда дели мой ответ?!